# Nodemailer: 4 mail over 8 are sent with empty body

Tags: node.js, email, web-applications, smtp, nodemailer

i'm building a management webapp for courses management. I have a mongodb with all my alumns , their email and their registration id. I wanna send the id to their mail. I have a html template and then with the fs.readfile and .replace() functions i replace the placeholders with the real infos i wanna send.

```
async function sendMail(mail,idreg){
  var html_template;
  const dataReg = "12/02/2019";
  const oraReg = "16:00";

  console.log(mail,idreg)

  fs.readFile("./html_template/beefree-9o6bg29htfb.html",(err,data)=>{
    html_template = data.toString().replace("XYZXYZXYZ",idreg).replace("XX/YY/ZZZZ",dataReg).replace("XX:YY",oraReg);
  });
  // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
  // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
  let account = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: "mymail@gmail.com ", // generated ethereal user
      pass: "mypw" // generated ethereal password
    }
  });
  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Cogestione Moscati" <mymail@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: mail, // list of receivers
    subject: "Il tuo codice di registrazione per la Cogestione", // Subject line
    html: html_template // html body
  };
  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
}
```

The problem is that i sent 8 times the same mail. 4 times i received correctly, 4 times i received with no body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code underneath your call to `fs.readFile` is not provided as part of the callback to that function. Basically, the file read is being kicked off and the rest of the code begins execution, resulting in a race to create `html_template` before the email is sent.

Two solutions:

1. Extend the callback to include the rest of the code. This would be the preferred method, as it is non-blocking and thus allows your application to continue serving other requests.
2. Use `fs.readFileSync`, the synchronous equivalent.

Also, since you are using async/await, you could also just `let data = await fs.readFile("path/to/file");`

Comment: let html_template = await fs.readFile("./html_template/beefree-9o6bg29htfb.html",(err,data)=>{
    return data.toString().replace("XYZXYZXYZ",idreg).replace("XX/YY/ZZZZ",dataReg).replace("XX:YY",oraReg);
  });

Comment: edit. i understood what you meant by "Extend the callback ". perfectly working. That's not a foult i usually do, because i manually write the code. In this case i copypasted from the docs. Thanks man! @tom-marsh